# cv2.hough circles error on video

Tags: python, linux, opencv, numpy

When I run cv2.HoughCircles() I am getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cv.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2,cv
  File "/home/jestinjoy/cv.py", line 19, in <module>
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2277, in around
    return _wrapit(a, 'round', decimals, out)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 37, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj),method)(*args, **kwds)
AttributeError: rint
```

My code is

GNU nano 2.2.6                                       File: cv.py

```
import cv2,cv
import numpy as np

cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
    rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
    rval = False

while rval:
        cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
        rval, frame = vc.read()
        img = cv2.medianBlur(frame,5)
        imgg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        cimg = cv2.cvtColor(imgg,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(imgg,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,10,param1=100,param2=30,minRadius=5,maxRadius=20)
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        for i in circles[0,:]:
               cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),1) # draw the outer circle
               cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3) # draw the center of the circle
        key = cv2.waitKey(20)
        if key == 27: # exit on ESC
                break
cv2.destroyWindow("preview")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not checking if you *circles* is None. If you do that, it works:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
    rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
    rval = False

while rval:
        cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        rval, frame = vc.read()
        img = cv2.medianBlur(frame,5)
        imgg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        cimg = cv2.cvtColor(imgg,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(imgg,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,10,param1=100,param2=30,minRadius=5,maxRadius=20)
        if circles is None:
                continue
        print circles
        #circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        for i in circles[0,:]:
               cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),1) # draw the outer circle
               cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3) # draw the center of the circle
        key = cv2.waitKey(20)
        if key == 27: # exit on ESC
                break
cv2.destroyWindow("preview")
```

Output generated:

```
sam@tuwien:/tmp$ python cv.py 
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
[[[ 335.5         368.5          10.12422848]]]
[[[ 334.5         386.5          10.12422848]]]
[[[ 349.5         382.5          10.12422848]]]
[[[ 392.5         365.5          10.12422848]]]
[[[ 378.5         370.5          10.12422848]]]
[[[ 378.5         368.5          12.34908867]]]
[[[ 391.5         369.5          14.57738018]]]
[[[ 379.5         370.5          10.12422848]]]
```

Comment: It doesn't print anything even if i show some circles

Comment: Can you post an image which is not working? Some your parameters might be wrong then. You should be able to see this: 

http://www.diabetesbluecircle.org/img/diabetesbluecircle.png 

print cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,3)

Comment: I think you should not remove the "accepted answer. Your initial question was the bug you were getting because you didn't check the variable. I found the bug and now you are claiming something else.

Answer (score 0):

Sam is correct, but his program does not draw the circles. Here is a fix:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
    rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
    rval = False

while rval:
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    img = cv2.medianBlur(frame,5)
    imgg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    cimg = cv2.cvtColor(imgg,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(imgg,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,10,param1=100,param2=30,minRadius=5,maxRadius=20)

    if circles is None:
        cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
        continue
    #circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

    for i in circles[0,:]:
       print i
       cv2.circle(frame,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),1) # draw the outer circle
       cv2.circle(frame,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3) # draw the center of the circle

    cv2.imshow("preview", frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(20)

    if key == 27: # exit on ESC
        break

cv2.destroyWindow("preview")
```

Answer (score 0):

This code needs some changes maybe due to same updates(obviously it was asked 2 yrs ago)
so i used ret instead of rval and also some changes in attributes of cv2.HoughCircles
Press q to exit.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
   ret, frame = vc.read()
else:
   ret = False

while True :
   ret, frame = vc.read()
   img = cv2.medianBlur(frame,15)
   imgg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
   cimg = cv2.cvtColor(imgg,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
   circles =   cv2.HoughCircles(imgg,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,120,param1=100,param2=30,minRadius=20,maxRadius=200)

   if circles is None:
       cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
       continue
   #circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

   for i in circles[0,:]:
      print i
      cv2.circle(frame,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),1) # draw the outer circle
      cv2.circle(frame,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3) # draw the center of the circle

   cv2.imshow("preview", frame)

   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break

vc.release()
cv2.destroyWindow("preview")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.